# How do I configure my apache2 webserver to allow access from anything within 192.168?

Tags: linux, apache2

Ok, so I've had my apache webserver running for a while now and it's all been going great. However, I just tried to access it via wifi:

```
Device running the web server: 192.168.0.99
Me: 192.168.1.8
```

192.168.0.* is a LAN connection. 192.168.1.* is a wireless connection.

I've tried this:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    Allow from 192.168
    Allow from 10
</Directory>
```

And restarted apache but got nowhere. Any suggestions?

If any more information is required, ask me and I'll add it.

Additional notes:

1. I can access it if I'm in the same range, e.g. 192.168.1.6
2. I get a connection timed out error from any device trying to access
   it.

Comment: Checked using `ping`?

Comment: Yep. Nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Potentially need to use some iptables commands. To check blocked ip's

```
 iptables -L INPUT -v -n
```

To allow all ips at home:

```
 iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -m iprange --src-range 192.168/16 -j ACCEPT
```

Here is an article with more information:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-howto-check-ip-blocked-against-iptables/